# ANSI Colours AWS CodeBuild Terminal Output

Tags: aws-codebuild

Does anybody know how to enable to ANSI colours int the AWS CodeBuild build logs. I've searched around for this and all I get is a reddit post about how AWS CodeBuild supports colours.

Example Output:

```
·[0m·[1mInitializing the backend...·[0m
·[0m·[32m
Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.·[0m
·[0m·[1mInitializing provider plugins...·[0m
- Checking for available provider plugins on
```

I was expecting to see some green and bold text, instead of the escape codes.

Comment: I have never found a way to enable this, so my approach has been to just make sure to disable color output on everything. Most well behaved tools should have an environment option or command line flags to stop them from emitting color codes, because not all backends support colored output.

Comment: yeah, just doing `-no-color` argument (e.g. `terraform init -no-color`) on every command((

Comment: To get around this issue without changing all commands or to disable colors when an external program runs terraform use `TF_CLI_ARGS = "-no-color"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you'd like to know I wrote a plugin that adds colors back into codebuild logs :)   https://github.com/joshuajwilborn/colorize-the-logs   I hope you enjoy it!

Comment: Haha ... well i guess after all this time ... this is the closest to an answer

Comment: @razboy wooo! Let me know how you like the plugin or if there is anything I can do to improve it.  It's open source, so feel free to file issues on github.